# Create dynamic input name with Zend Form

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, zend-form

I would like to make my Zend_Form_Element_Text dynamic, i.e it will accept different input name.

I have this:

```
 $email = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('email');
```

It create an input with 'email' as the name:

```
 <input name="email" id="email" size="20" maxlength="100" placeholder="Email" class="input" type="text">
```

But sometimes I receive some external POST request and their input name field are different, like this:

```
 <input name="login_Email" id="email" size="20" maxlength="100" placeholder="Email" class="input" type="text">
```

Can you please guide me how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, I guess you have something like this to get POST variables:

```
if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
    $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

    if ($form->isValid($formData)) {
    ....
```

So you can test each POST variable, if it matches than 'email' and not equals to 'email', you can create a new email variable POST

```
if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
    $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

    foreach($formData as $name => $value){      
        if ($name != 'email' && preg_match("/email/i", $name))
            $formData['email'] = $value;
    }
    if ($form->isValid($formData)) {
    ...
```